# Is it possible to remove an app's results from Modern UI search on the start screen?

Tags: search, windows-8, windows-search, modern-ui

How can I remove all search items (for example emails) from a particular pre-installed Modern UI app when searching by typing on the start screen?

Comment: Do you want to remove search history from the start screen?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'll edit that into my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Windows-8 Charm Bar by moving the mouse pointer to the top-right/lower-right corner of the screen and click on **Settings**. Alternatively you can directly press the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> hotkey to open the `Settings` sidebar. Here click on the `Change PC Settings` link at the bottom to open Windows-8 Modern UI settings.

[image]

Navigate to **Search** settings in `PC settings` and click on the button **Delete history** to delete all the searches you have performed.

To disable the search history tracker, toggle the `Let Windows save my searches as future search` suggestions settings from on to off.

When you disable the history tracker, the Delete history button will be disabled as all your history will be deleted automatically.

If you want to disable Windows-8 search on any of the app, you can switch if off as well and omit the app from showing results in the start screen.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have put that at the last of my post, as it could be depend on the users. But is you think it need any edit you are free for that :)